# How to use RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding in Go?

Tags: go, encryption, rsa

## Java

Example plaintext = "6122005564598"

```
public String encryptData(String certId, String plantext) throws Exception {
        String b64UmpsCert = umpsEncCertStore.getCert(certId);
        
        byte[] bUmpsCert = Base64.decodeBase64(b64UmpsCert);
        X509Certificate x509Cert;
        try {
            x509Cert = CertificateUtil.recoverEncodedX509Certificate(bUmpsCert);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new Exception("unable to read umps sign cert", e);
        }
        
        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)x509Cert.getPublicKey();
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        // 6122005564598 plantext
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plantext.getBytes());

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
```

## Go

I use  crypto/rsa EncryptPKCS1v15. But can't correct generate.

```
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(filename))
if block == nil {
    fmt.Println("Decode err")
}
// Parse certificate
cert, errParse := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)

// 6122005564598 plantext
encypt, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(
    rand.Reader,
    cert.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey),
    []byte(plantext)
)
return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(encypt)
```

But can't correct this encrypt. I connecting UnionPay.

Comment: You need to provide more information about why it is not working for you. An obvious issue with the code is that the second argument to `EncryptPKCS1v15` should be `pub.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)` instead of what you have - but it is unclear if that is the problem you're facing. A second issue is that there is a typo in the variable passed to `EncodeToString`, it should be `encrypt` instead of `encypt`

Comment: I edited the source code. Can you agian review my code ?